# Exception when connecting to a URL with jsoup

Tags: java, android, eclipse, exception, jsoup

**This is my Debug stack:**

```
Thread [<1> main] (Suspended (exception IllegalArgumentException))  
<VM does not provide monitor information>   
HttpConnection.connect(String) line: 30 
Jsoup.connect(String) line: 73  
Parsing.doInBackground(String...) line: 23  
MainActivity$1.onClick(View) line: 29   
Button(View).performClick() line: 4424  
View$PerformClick.run() line: 18383 
Handler.handleCallback(Message) line: 733   
ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 95 
Looper.loop() line: 137 
ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 4998    
Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method]  
Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 515  
ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 777  
ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 593
```

ing

Here is my code :

```
package com.example.pricetracker;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;

import android.os.AsyncTask;


public class Parsing extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {


    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Document htmlFile = null; 
        Element price = null;

          try {

               htmlFile = Jsoup.connect("www.amazon.in/Google-Nexus-D821-16GB-Black/dp/B00GC1J55C/ref=sr_1_1?s=electronics&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;qid=1421161258&amp;sr=1-1&amp;keywords=Google").get();
          } catch (IOException ex) {
              // TODO Auto-generated catch block
              ex.printStackTrace();
          }         
          catch (Exception ex) {
              // TODO Auto-generated catch block
              ex.printStackTrace();
          }         

        try{

          if( htmlFile.getElementById("priceblock_ourprice")!= null)
          {
            price = htmlFile.getElementById("priceblock_ourprice");
          }
          else
          {
            price = htmlFile.getElementById("priceblock_saleprice");

          }   
        }catch(Exception e)
          {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }

        return (String)price.toString();

    }
```

How to get the data from the URL?

What is the cause of this problem and How can I solve this?

I'm stuck here for more than a day.

Any ideas folks? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a URL that specifies the scheme as well (http or https):

```
htmlFile = Jsoup.connect("http://www.amazon.in/Google-Nexus-D821-16GB-Black/dp/B00GC1J55C/ref=sr_1_1?s=electronics&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;qid=1421161258&amp;sr=1-1&amp;keywords=Google").get();
                         ^^^^^^^^
```

**Edit**

From the [JavaDoc for JSoup.connect(String)](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Jsoup.html#connect(java.lang.String)):

```
> url - URL to connect to. The protocol must be http or https.
```

Comment: Hi @Todd, I checked the API - http://jsoup.org/apidocs/ and didn't find any such method. Did I miss anything?

Comment: Oh! I didn't get that before. I added "http://" and now ran into a different exception. I'll edit the question. Please look at it. Thanks @Todd.

Comment: It's best to add a new question, or none of this will make sense in hindsight/context. Also, it's probably a good idea for you to try and fix it yourself first, that's how we learn.

Comment: Okay! I revererted changes and restored question's original state.

Comment: here is the question for next exception raised - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28013394/gaiexception-when-connecting-to-a-url-with-jsoup  Please have a look Todd! :)